# Will Bing bot index pages with invalid SSL certificates?

Tags: https, yahoo, bingbot

Bingbot and Yahoo Slurp do not support SNI (Server Name Indication) when using SSL.  Ignoring other workarounds (multi domain certificates, non-SSL content etc.). Will Bingbot index pages that have an invalid SSL certificate, eg: issued for **`example.net`**, but used on **`example.com`**?  If possible please provide an example from Yahoo or Bing.

I have found websites in Bing, that use self signed certificates and are indexed correctly, but what about invalid certificates?

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: As Martin points out, Bing can still index the site with SSL links in SERPS even though it errors on SNI -- the error occurs before the following results. The following is arbirtary for the question.

Bing does support SNI [Edit: as in it can still successfully index SSL links]. Im looking at a multidomain multiSSL via SNI setup right now, clicking the SERP results drop me https. Also, looking at 30 minute sessions, the last pages it crawled are all https-mode.

Based on past esperiences with sharedSSL and TLD derivitaves -- if a certificate is invalid, for another domain, or whatever, there is about a 99% chance it wont index. If it does index, most likely it will flag a warning in SERP or it wont stick. We have a site that has invalid SSL and malconfigured subdomain SSL (since its SNI server) and even though the https there is accessable, and various links point https, it has never been indexed with its non-accurate [invalid] SSLmode.

Hope i understood what you were asking!

Comment: You understand correctly, but I would not agree with your findings, at least from the time I wrote the question.  If you try the SSLStrictSNIVHostCheck option in Apache, you can see, that Bing is served the error code, indicating that it does not support SNI.  Bing will however still crawl the sites.

Comment: Ah my apologies, i misuderstood the point at which the incompatibilities occur. I should have asked how you found error. Im noticing too, Qualys is saying BingBot2013 doesn't technically support ForwardSecrecy either. So my answer stinks, minus the subjective "our site didnt index with an invalid SSL"...which also provides no evidence :) I have edited the answer with your findings.